# PHP Symfony 2 passing class containing sockets between controllers

Tags: php, sockets, symfony

I am using PHP 5.5.9 and Symfony 2.2.7,
I need to pass an array of class that contains an array of PHP sockets between controllers.
The troubles I get is that I can't pass it through a session that puts a 0 instead of the socket, when I try to pass it through a service that was each time reset the class, then I try to put the array in static but that doesn't work too.

Did anyone have a clue, a track or something to help me?

Thanks for reading at least and have a good day.

Here is the class who ecapsul the sockets:

```
class Socket {
private $socket;
private $give;
private static $out;


function __construct($host, $port = -1){
    $errno = 0;
    $errmsg = "";
    $this->give = false;
    if ($port === -1) {
        $this->socket = $host->getFd();
        $this->give = true;
    }
    else {
        $this->socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errmsg);
        echo "connection\n";
    }
}

function __destruct() {
    if (!$this->give && !$this->socket === false)
        fclose($this->socket);
}

function getFd() {
    return ($this->socket);
}

function writeSocket($buff, $size) {
    if ($this->socket === false)
        return (false);
    echo "send: " . bin2hex($buff) . "\n";
    return (fwrite($this->socket, $buff, $size));
}

function readSocket($size) {
    if ($this->socket === false)
        return (false);
    $out = "";
    $out = fgets($this->socket, $size + 1);
    if (strlen($out) < $size) {
        $tmp = fgets($this->socket, $size - strlen($out) + 1);
        if (!($tmp === false))
            $out .= $tmp;
    }
    echo "read: " . bin2hex($out) . "\n";
    return ($out);
}
```

}

Here the class that implement the procol:

```
class EcoProtocol{
private $socket;
private $isLogged;
private $orga;
private $pass;
private $user;
private $KO;

/**
 * Initiate the connexion to the server
 * and read the first packet from the server
 */
public function __construct(){
    $this->socket = new Socket("91.121.11.33", 4340);
}

public function logIn($new, $user, $pass) {
    //using socket here
}
```

}

And here the class with the array:

```
class ConnexionsHandler {
private static $socket;
private $maxTime = 120;

function __construct(){
    echo "construct";
    if (!isset(ConnexionsHandler::$socket))
    {
        echo "is not set";
        ConnexionsHandler::$socket = array();
    }
    print_r(ConnexionsHandler::$socket);
}

function __destruct(){
    echo "destruct";
}

private function cleanConnexion(){
    foreach (ConnexionsHandler::$socket as $key => $val) {
        if (time() - $val[0] > $this->maxTime){
            unset(ConnexionsHandler::$socket[$key]);
        }
    }
}

public function getConnexion($user){
    $this->cleanConnexion();
    if (array_key_exists($user, ConnexionsHandler::$socket)){
        ConnexionsHandler::$socket[$user][0] = time();
        return (ConnexionsHandler::$socket[$user][1]);
    }
    return (null);
}

public function createConnexion($new, $user, $pass){
    $this->cleanConnexion();
    $client = new EcoProtocol();
    $ret = $client->logIn($new, $user, $pass);
    ConnexionsHandler::$socket[$user][0] = time();
    ConnexionsHandler::$socket[$user][1] = $client;
    return ($ret);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: A socket is a resource, you know, you can't serialize them in session.

Comment: It's what I have understand, I add the class.